# How to model an enumeration class?

Tags: uml

An attribute of a class is an enumeration. How do i model this?

Normally you do something like this: **`- name : string`**

But how to do this with an enum? , what is the standard uml representation of enum ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An `enumeration` is a data type whose values are enumerated in the model as user-defined enumeration literals.

An `enumeration` may be shown using the classifier notation (a rectangle) with the keyword `«enumeration»`. The name of the enumeration is placed in the upper compartment. A compartment listing the attributes for the enumeration is placed below the name compartment. A compartment listing the operations for the enumeration is placed below the attribute compartment.

A list of enumeration literals may be placed, one to a line, in the bottom compartment. The attributes and operations compartments may be suppressed, and typically are suppressed if they would be empty.

**Example**

```
 _____________________
|   <<enumeration>>   |
|    DaysOfTheWeek    |
|_____________________|
| Sunday              |
| Monday              |
| Tuesday             |
| ...                 |
|_____________________|
```

Such an enumeration can be used as a datatype for attributes and parameters.
So your attribute would be shown as

```
- Day : DaysOfTheWeek
```